# Laplace transform, How to calculate the output of a system to a infinitely extending signal?

Tags: signal, laplace-transform, system

I need to calculate the output of a system given as

\begin{align*}
H(s) = \frac{s}{(s+1)(s+2)}
\end{align*}

For an input
\begin{align*}
e^{3t}   \  \ \ \ \forall \ t
\end{align*}

I currently understand that Laplace transforms do not exist for signals that extends to infinity on both sides. In this case how do I find the output of the above system for the given input?

Comment: If you were to search for a table of transforms (such as the one on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms)), what is the Laplace transform for your signal?

Answer (score 2):

Bilateral Laplace transform is defined from -∞ to +∞.

Laplace transform is defined from 0 to +∞.

Try  transform your exponential function using the bilateral transform.